# Problem on Combinations allowing repetition with no missing element.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let's consider a problem :

Find all five-digit combinations from the set $\{1,2,3\}$ with no missing digits.

I don't understand how the solution for this problem can be mapped to

${k-1 \choose n-1}$

Where $k$ is length of combination and $n$ is number of elements.

Is there any other intuitive method to solve this problem ?

Comment: This is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) question (Theorem 1 on the link). If you read the proof there, you'll understand how the counting works, and it is quite intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be mapped to the stars and bars problem. You have the $k$ stars and $n-1$ bars. The total combinations is ${ k + n - 1} \choose {n-1}$ if you allow empty urns. In your case, you don't want to allow empty urns, and this is equivalent to saying you want a star in each urn. Thus, you can just place a star in each urn and then use the regular stars and bars method to partition the remaining stars, allowing empty urns. 
Therefore, you now only have $k - n$ stars to partition, and ${k  - 1} \choose {n-1}$ total combinations.